# Does Vue have ElementType in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-riz99b?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FAppChildren.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FCustom1.tsx&terminal=dev)

```js
// react use ElelentType
import { ElementType } from 'react'


// vue use what ?
import { Component } from 'vue'
```

I hope vue can pass components like react

Answer (score 0):

[reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs)

> In order to get the instance type of a component, you need to first
> get its type via typeof, then use TypeScript's built-in InstanceType
> utility to extract its instance type